# Batch insert nodes with neo4jclient using Bolt

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am trying to import N nodes in to neo4j using the neo4jclient. I am using a neo4j cluster hosted in Azure so I must use the Bolt protocol. So I am using the RC1 of neo4jclient.

Based on examples that I will include below I have the following code:

```
BoltGraphClient client =
    new BoltGraphClient(new Uri("bolt://myserver:7687"), "neo4j", "mypwd");
client.Connect();

var nodes = new List<myNode>()
   {
      new myNode()
      {
         id = "a",
         patientKey = "aaa",
         patient_fname = "John",
         patient_lname = "Doe"
      },
      new myNode()
      {
         id = "b",
         patientKey = "bbb",
         patient_fname = "Jane",
         patient_lname = "Doe"
      }
  };

client.Cypher
    .Create("(n:Node {nodes})")
    .WithParams(new { nodes })
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

I am getting the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException occurred
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

I believe that I have followed the following answer that is supposed to work: [Batch insert nodes and relations neo4jclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868905/batch-insert-nodes-and-relations-neo4jclient)

I am using Neo4j 3.2.6, Neo4jClient 3RC1 and c# 4.6

If all looks good then I will create a defect for Neo4jClient.

Comment: Create a bug and if you can provide a small self contained example that'd be great!

Comment: Actually - I can't get that to work with the normal REST endpoint either - which is odd. The deserialisation error *is* an error - but to get your query to work - I would do something like: `.Unwind(nodes, "node").Create("(n:Node)").Set("n = node")`

Comment: Although - having just tested that - same error.. lemme fix that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Neo4jClient 3.0.0-RC2` has just been published. I can't get the query you specifically have to run, so I'm going to play with that, but I get the same error from both `Neo4jClient` and the official `Neo4j.Driver` so I assume it's a change that means that Cypher no longer works.

However, you will find with `RC2` you can do:

```
client.Cypher
    .Unwind(nodes, "node")
    .Create("(n:Node)")
    .Set("n = node")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

which is the way I would do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thx!