# Optimize Create

Tags: cypher, neo4jclient

I got 20 000 apples.

How do I create them in a smarter way than this?

```
        foreach (var a in apples)
        {
            graphClient.Cypher
                .Create("(a:Apple {newApple})")
                .WithParam("newApple", a)
                .ExecuteWithoutResults();
        }
```

Looking for a generic way to be able to pass objects without specifying each property.

```
class Fruit
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Color")]
    public bool Color { get; set; }
}

class Apple : Fruit
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Variety")]
    public String Variety { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose `apples` is a list of dictionaries. In that case, a more optimized query in plain Cypher would look like this:

```
UNWIND {apples} AS newApple
CREATE (a:Apple)
SET a = newApple
```

I have not yet used the Neo4jClient .NET lib, but something along these lines should work:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Unwind(apples, "newApple")
    .Create("(a:Apple)")
    .Set(...)
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

20k nodes might work in a single transaction, but it's worth to implement some batching and use batches of approx. 10k nodes.

**Update.** Updated the implementation per Chris Skardon's suggestion.

**Remark.** In the Cypher query, if you are using Neo4j 3.2+, you should switch to the [new parameter syntax](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters-introduction), that uses `$param` style parameters, so the query is slightly easier to read:

```
UNWIND $apples AS newApple
CREATE (a:Apple)
SET a = newApple
```

Comment: With the client, you can just do `.Unwind(apples, "newApple" )` and dispense with the `WithParam` bit.

Comment: Unwind seems like the way to go but I keep getting `Neo4jClient.NeoException: 'ParameterNotFoundException: Expected a parameter named newApple'` and can't see why right now

Comment: @JOG I updated my answer to use `SET` instead of doing it in a single `CREATE`.

Comment: Can I make that work for generic objects? updating my Q with classes

Comment: You can definitely make it work by extracting the properties from the object (node) with `properties(newApple)`. However, before you do that, you need to pass the node from the driver, which currently does not work over the Bolt protocol - see [this issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/10239).

Comment: Marking as answer and extracting the `ParameterNotFoundException` question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48061073/237509

Comment: I believe the `ParameterNotFoundException` issue is fixed with `SET`, please double check.

Comment: You are correct. `.Set("a = newApple")` did the trick, if you want to update. Thanks for your patience and help :)