# ParameterNotFoundException when not setting specific params

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am trying to use Neo4jClient to run the Cypher syntax:

```
    UNWIND {apples} AS newApple
    CREATE (a:Apple {newApple})
```

with a C# list of object `List<Apple> a` where the object could be:

```
class Apple : Fruit
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Variety")]
    public String Variety { get; set; }
}
```

I do not want to spread out object variable specs in different places around the code.

But running

```
            graphClient.Cypher
                .Unwind(a, "newApple")
                .Create("(a: Apple {newApple})")
                .ExecuteWithoutResults()
```

throws:

> Neo4jClient.NeoException: 'ParameterNotFoundException: Expected a parameter named newApple'

Changing the `Create` row to

```
            .Create("(a: Apple {Id: newApple.Id})")
```

seems to work though, so the expected parameter `newApple` is found. The problem here is that if I change the properties of the class, I have to change the direct dependency in the cypher query string.

## Questions

1. Why is this? I would expect the identifier specified in `Unwind` would be found in both cases.
2. Any workaround so that I can keep the generalized code? I aim to be able to send in any POCO object to automatically match with neo node type params.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `newApple` is no longer a parameter, but a variable, whereas the syntax used by you can only be applied with external parameters.

For variables can be used this way:

```
WITH [{id: 1, name: 'appe1'}, {id: 2, name: 'apple2'}] as apples
UNWIND apples as newApple
CREATE (a:Apple) SET a = newApple
RETURN a
```

Comment: So how can I do this with arbitrary POCO's in the c# neo4jclient?

Comment: Something like this: `...Create("(a: Apple)").Set("a = newApple")...`

Comment: But you are still specifying vars/params in the query here, `name: 'appe1'`. I aim to just throw in an object with JsonProperties. Amending that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Gabor's answer, for C# neo4jclient that can be achieved like this (unfolding in comments and edits [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47361119/237509)):

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Unwind(apples, "newApple")
    .Create("(a: Apple)")
    .Set("a = newApple")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

`SET` allows setting the whole object with JsonAttribute properties, without specifying explicit parameters in cypher.